# android sqlite syntax error selection

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an error when I call this method:

```
public void updateEnrolled(String name, String group, boolean enrolled) 
{
    Cursor cursor = database.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_DATE, KEY_PROFESSOR, KEY_LOCATION, KEY_HOURSTART, KEY_HOUREND, KEY_WEEK}, KEY_NAME + "=" +name, null, null, null, null, null);// + " AND " + KEY_GROUP + "=" + group
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
    {
        long rowId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID));
        String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE));
        String professor = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PROFESSOR));
        String location = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_LOCATION));
        String hourStart = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_HOURSTART));
        String hourEnd = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_HOUREND));
        int week = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_WEEK));
        updateLesson(rowId,name,date,professor,location,hourStart,hourEnd,week,group,enrolled);
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

The error I get is:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Electronics": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT _id, date, professor, location, hourStart, hourEnd, week FROM lesson WHERE name=Analog Electronics: lab
```

I have tried another input too and it it every time the second word of the name that gives the error. 
Can anyone help me?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `KEY_NAME + "= \"" + name + "\""` in your database.query method

Comment: I call it with values from a database: 
lessonDb.updateEnrolled(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), enrolled);
And I tried using KEY_NAME + "=\"" + name + "\"" in the query above, but then my app just gets stuck

Comment: What do you mean stuck? What is the DDMS output?

Comment: It was just stuck but I found the problem already. It isn't doing what I want yet but it doesn't give an error anymore and it doesn't get stuck anymore. But your answer was right. The reason my program got stuck was because I forgot the cursor.moveToNext() in the while loop. I always forget that one. Stupid. Anyway, thanks!!!